# How do I use a SAEF / Channel Form to upload a file not related to entry?

Tags: safecracker, file-uploads, files, safecracker-file

Is there any way to use a SAEF / Channel Form to upload an image (with title, category etc.)?

Will it require a custom plugin or is this something that can be achieved already?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SAEF does just what it says - creates new entries from outside the Control Panel. You could look to use Solspace Freeform to create a form that allows image uploads outside of Channel:Entries.

Alternatively you could just dedicate a channel for your file uploads if you want to assign meta data to each image.

Comment: I was thinking about this last night and came to a similar solution. I didn't think about Freeform though so good call on that. I have also found a plugin that will help called Channel Images / Files. It works perfectly for what I need but thank you for your answer.